# Problemas con Fortify y php The function curl_init

Tags: php, seguridad

Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un proyecto en **php** y lo he escaneado con **fortify** y me arroja el siguiente error:

> Resumen
>
> The function curl_init() on line 153 initiates a network connection to
> a third-party system using user-controlled data for resource URI. An
> attacker might leverage this vulnerability to send a request on behalf
> of the application server since the request will originate from the
> application server's internal IP address.The application initiates a
> network connection to a third-party system using user-controlled data
> to craft the resource URI.
>
> Explicación
>
> A Server-Side Request Forgery occurs when an attacker may influence a
> network connection made by the application server. The network
> connection will originate from the application server's internal IP
> address and an attacker will be able to use this connection to bypass
> network controls and scan or attack internal resources that are not
> otherwise exposed.

La linea de codigo que tengo en mi php es:

```
function consultar_ws($url,$headers,$payload){
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
        return $response;
    }
```

donde **URL** es una variable compuesta por un valor de entorno + una dirección, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Desde donde viene el valor de las variables `$payload` y `$headers`?

Comment: De la misma página, esa función es llamada en la misma.pagina el header es un array con datos de la cabera como el token y y la.varianle payload es un json que viene resultado de una consulta

Comment: Lo que intenta decirte **Fortify** es que algunos de estos datos, y creo que es exactamente `$url` no proviene de un lugar totalmente seguro, provocando un tipo de vulnerabilidad llamado [**SSRF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_request_forgery). O sea que estos datos los provee el usuario en algún momento, y puede ser fácil que el mismo inyecte datos maliciosos en la solicitud

Comment: Realmente la variable url esta compuesta, en una parte por el valor de una variable de entorno, que por lo general es el dominio de dónde está la es, y otra parte es ladirecciin co los parámetros para la consulta, ejemplo
$var1 = www.acaestamiws.com/ y $var2 = carpetas/ws?val=1 y así, hay alguna manera de burlar ducha advertencia?